# Code left behind in Form1.Designer.vb

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have a strange intermittent issue.

Occasionally after removing controls from a VB form, some code gets left behind in the `Form1.Designer.vb` file and is visible in the solution explorer as well. All the textboxes in the screenshot were deleted from the form by highlighting them and deleting them. There is no other related code left behind .. just this.

I haven't been able to find the conditions when this happens either.

Does anyone have any idea why? I guess it isn't a big issue, but I don't know if there are any significant implications.

[image]

Comment: it's strange but try to **Clean and Rebuild** the solution

Comment: Yep. Tried that. No difference.

Comment: An exception at design-time can easily cause this kind of mishap.  Anything is possible, nothing is obvious.

Comment: To the close voter, The question is not about programming, it is about the tools used for programming and therefore still on topic even though not a coding question